# variability in file extension batch file

Tags: batch-file

this is a line from my batch file script :

```
del "AAN*.xlsx"
```

I want to delete any file that has a name starting with AAN and ending with either '.xls' or '.xlsx'
I can't do:

```
del "AAN*.xls*"
```

because it would delete the file

```
 'AANN.xlsx.csv'  as well.
```

is there a way to code it so that it would delete either .xlsx or .xls? I tried:

```
del "AAN*.xls(x)"
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Why not issue two del commands, one for `del "AAN*.xlsx"` and one for `del "AAN*.xls"` or `del "AAN*.xlsx" "AAN*.xls"`?

Comment: `del "AAN*.xls?"` comes closer to what you want, but still it would also match `AAN*.xlst`, for instance. Since Windows `cmd` commands do not support regular expressions, it is simply not possible to specify a single expression. You can however provide multiple arguments to `del`, like @MrTux demonstrated...

Comment: @MrTux because my file has different extension each month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not issue two del commands, one for `del "AAN*.xlsx"` and one for `del "AAN*.xls"` or combine them to one command:

```
del "AAN*.xlsx" "AAN*.xls"
```